# Ruby on Rails error - No route matches [GET] "/redmine"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm installing redmine (www.redmine.org) on an managed server, had some problems with the FCGI integration in Apache and I solved them. Now I don't get 'internal server error', I have a new errormessage from my redmine installation:

```
No route matches [GET] “/redmine”
Rails.root: /usr/www/users/admin/redmine-4.0.4

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes
Routes match in priority from top to bottom
```

and a lot of routes.

redmine works from the internal server (rails s) so it seems to be a problem with apache or rails.

This is my FCGI configuration:

**.htaccess** is:

```
FcgidWrapper /usr/www/users/admin/redmine/ruby_handler.fcgi .rb
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ruby_handler.fcgi [QSA,L]
```

**ruby_handler.fcgi** is:

```
#!/bin/dash
#export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/"
#export GEM_PATH="$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0"

export HOME="/usr/home/admin"
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem/ruby/"
export GEM_PATH="/usr/home/admin/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/"

exec /usr/bin/ruby /usr/www/users/admin/redmine/startup.rb
```

**startup.rb** is:

```
require_relative ‘config/environment’

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
def initialize(app)
@app = app
end

def call(env)
env.delete(‘SCRIPT_NAME’)
parts = env[‘REQUEST_URI’].split(’?’)
env[‘PATH_INFO’] = parts[0]
env[‘QUERY_STRING’] = parts[1].to_s
env[‘HOME’] = “/usr/home/admin/”
@app.call(env)
end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(RedmineApp::Application)
```

Any tipps how to fix this?

Comment: Try looking at this old thread: https://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/30676?r=30881

Comment: Honestly I recommend running Redmine via passenger or ngnix or some other app server & reverse proxying...

Comment: Thanks - I will try the suggestions in the redmine.org thread.

And I'll prefer passenger too - but it's managed server and not available from my provider

Comment: I tried the tipps in old redmine.org thread and added the scope to the routes.rb - it works!

Last problem - stylesheets, images etc. are not loaded, they are in /redmine/public but in the html /redmine/ is referred.

Comment: You can try resolving that with .htaccess file https://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/15709 also please answer your own question so that others can see what you did. Thanks!

Comment: I solved this by creating symbolic links to the missing folders :)